# EOL while scanning string literal in Python menu

Tags: python, eol

You won´t be able to run the script, sadly I don´t know why.
It's about EOL but I'm not that much into python so I need your help,
I´ve tried different stuff and didn't work. Also, my friend that actually is into phyton tried and failed.

this is just a menu code for running multiple antiviruses whenever I want to check my computer

```
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting
def menu():
    print ("Welcome To S1MPL3 MENU, an simple made antivirus for open Wi-Fi and Computer Repair.\n 1. Easy File Check \n 2.Total Time Security \n 3.Suspicius Ip Check")
    choice = input()

    if choice == "1":
        print("Checking Files ... (The process wont take long !")
        os.chdir 'C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\Core_Files\Projects\S1mpl3 Antivirus\Check\Files\File_Check.vbs\
        menu()

    if choice == "2":
        print("TTS Chosen!")
        os.chdir  'C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\Projects\S1mpl3_Antivirus\Check\\Files\Ip_Check\'
        menu()

    if  choice == "3":
         print("Checking For Suspicius Ip in your Home Wi-Fi")
         os.chdir 'C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\Core_Files\Projects\S1mpl3 Antivirus\Check\Files\Ip_Check\'
         menu()

menu()
```

The error should be in the S1m of choice 2

> Error: Syntax Error  EOL while scanning string literal

Answer (score 1):

You are using backslash characters '\' in your paths. While this is OK on the command line, it is (mostly) not correct in source code. The backslash character is used as escape character to change the meaning of the following character. In your case the trailing apostroph is escaped so that the path string is not closed.

You can use a raw string like @RonaldAaronson proposed:

```
r'C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\Projects\S1mpl3_Antivirus\Check\Files\Ip_Check\'
```

Or replace all single backslash with double like this:

```
'C:\\Users\\alexa\\Desktop\\Projects\\S1mpl3_Antivirus\\Check\\Files\\Ip_Check\\'
```

Many Windows function also work with the unixoid path separator '/', and `os.chdir()` does so, too:

```
os.chdir('C:/Users/alexa/Desktop/Projects/S1mpl3_Antivirus/Check/Files/Ip_Check')
```

The library `os` has `os.sep` and `os.altsep` that are pathname separators. Use these to write better portable code. Please read the documentation. This is always a good idea.

Second observation: You need to call `os.chdir()` with parentheses.

Comment: Didn´t work at all. the problem now is on a backlash instead of in the "s1m"

Comment: @IM Sorry, I didn't check the resulting HTML after writing the answer. Did you double the backslashes like is visible now?

Comment: Or use a raw string literal such as `r'C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\Projects\S1mpl3_Antivirus\Check\Files\Ip_Check\'`

Comment: @RonaldAaronson Right. ;-) I'm not sure which one is the pythonic way.

Comment: From the manual: **Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and treat backslashes as literal characters. As a result, in string literals, '\U' and '\u' escapes in raw strings are not treated specially.**

Comment: Doesn't work anyway (at least in my computer) I´ve tried all and It didn´t work. this is what I have know: os.chdir() r'C:\\Users\\alexa\\Desktop\\Projects\\S1mpl3_Antivirus\\Check\\Files\\Ip_Check\\'. I have tried all the ways and didn't work. BTW thanks for all support.

Comment: Please read careful what we wrote and compare with what you are using. You will see the difference and I hope you will understand what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a single quote at the end of the line:

```
if choice == "1":
        print("Checking Files ... (The process wont take long !")
        os.chdir 'C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\Core_Files\Projects\S1mpl3 Antivirus\Check\Files\File_Check.vbs\   **<---here**
        menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem while opening a directory. I used raw string and double backslashes and it works. Example:

```py
os.chdir(r"C:\\Users\\alexa\Desktop\\Core_Files\\Projects\\S1mpl3Antivirus\\Check\\Files\\")
```